# Getting the current coordinates after rotate/translate Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, transformation

I’m stuck trying to figure out how to use `.getTransform` to determine what point A `x1/y1` and point B `x2/y2`of each of my lines would be after translate and rotate. I've found other answers but they don't seem to target exactly what I need nor do I fully understand the matrix that gets returned.

From the snippet provided you can see that my lines always return their original values. I know there's a formula for this I just don't know it or how I would implement it.

What I need is the start and end points of every line. The plan will be to rotate (animated spinning) them to any angle and have those coordinates get used for ray casting. I've previously done this from a center point out or one direction to another but not with so many lines using the rotate method.

Here's the snippet

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 180;

class Rays {
  constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(45 * (Math.PI/180))
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1)
    ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

let rays = [];
function createRays() {
  //due to translate i have to push some lines in the negative and some positive  this causes an overlap of one line in the center.
  for (let i=0; i < 26; i++) {
    let x1 =  i < 13 ? -10 * i : i * 10 - canvas.width/2 - 20;
    let y1 =  -canvas.height;
    let x2 =  i < 13 ? -10 * i : i * 10 - canvas.width/2 - 20;
    let y2 =  canvas.height;
    rays.push(new Rays(x1, y1, x2, y2));  
  }
}
//enter angle here
createRays();

let count = 0; //just used to stop it from constantly console logging rays.x1

function drawRays() {
  for (let i=0;i<rays.length; i++) {
    rays[i].draw();
    count < 1 ? console.log(rays[i].x1) : false;
  }
  count++
}
drawRays();

console.log(ctx.getTransform())

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    drawRays();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPointReadOnly) interface which does provide a `.matrixTransform(DOMMatrix)` method.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 180;

const mat = new DOMMatrix();
mat.translateSelf(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
mat.rotateSelf(45);

class Rays {
  constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    const pt1 = new DOMPoint(x1, y1).matrixTransform(mat);
    const pt2 = new DOMPoint(x2, y2).matrixTransform(mat);
        
    this.x1 = pt1.x;
    this.y1 = pt1.y;
    this.x2 = pt2.x;
    this.y2 = pt2.y;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1)
    ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2)
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

let rays = [];
function createRays() {
  //due to translate i have to push some lines in the negative and some positive  this causes an overlap of one line in the center.
  for (let i=0; i < 26; i++) {
    let x1 =  i < 13 ? -10 * i : i * 10 - canvas.width/2 - 20;
    let y1 =  -canvas.height;
    let x2 =  i < 13 ? -10 * i : i * 10 - canvas.width/2 - 20;
    let y2 =  canvas.height;
    rays.push(new Rays(x1, y1, x2, y2));  
  }
}
//enter angle here
createRays();

let count = 0; //just used to stop it from constantly console logging rays.x1

function drawRays() {
  for (let i=0;i<rays.length; i++) {
    rays[i].draw();
  }
  count++
}
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
drawRays();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This does answer my question. I do have a couple more that hopefully you can answer. Does this have any disadvantages over getTransform? Does it have any advantages? Can this same technique be used for all shapes? Like maybe I decide to do rotating rectangles that require collision detection. I really appreciate the great answer.

Comment: getTransform will itself return a DOMMatrix, so you can do exactly the same from there, however, if you redraw the points at their transformed positions without changing the context's transform in between, your points will get transformed twice. Note also that you can pass that DOMMatrix to `setTransform` if needed. Then note that `isPointInPath` takes the current context's transform into account, so it might also be an option. If you need an identity matrix, the constructor might have a faster path, but all in all, no great winner no, depends on your project's structure.

Comment: And yes, you can transform all the points of a polygon to transform that polygon.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me what I need to do to animate these lines and make them rotate? It doesn't seem to matter what I try they won't animate but rather just inherit the initial position. I've tried placing them in the animate loop and outside with a `angle` variable that increments. amongst other things that seem like they should work.

Comment: If you only want to draw these lines, animated, then the best is certainly to use the context's transform directly: https://jsfiddle.net/t63adsu1/ If you wanted to update your points and need to read back the values, then you would have to  create a new DOMMatrix and probably new DOMPoints too every frames, which can be quite ineficient.

Comment: Yeah the end goal would be to have them roatate while updating the vectors for the purpose of Raycasting. Without updated ptA and ptB every frame then the raycasting wouldn’t work as my goal is to highlight a shape everytime they pass through it but only at the intersect points.

Comment: Then you can simply keep the original points, render them as in my fiddle, and just read their updated values by doing `new DOMPoint(x, y).matrixTransform(ctx.getTransform())`. I guess that would be the simplest.